# UDF to Create Hyperlink to Location in Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, user-defined-functions

I am seeking VBA for an Excel UDF that creates a hyperlink to a designated cell ("MyCell") of the active workbook. MyCell can be on any worksheet of the workbook that contains the UDF. All examples I have seen so far have been too complicated for me to edit the code properly.

```
Function MyHyperLink(MyCell)

'Code?

End Function
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But if it's a UDF, how will it be "clickable"? Can you also clarify why the `HYPERLINK` function isn't good enough?

Comment: Yikes @BigBen, I forgot that existed. That looks like it does exactly what the OP wants. Now I'm a bit embarrassed about my answer. I guess this is how we stay sharp. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to what you want to do. One is the getting the address of the hyperlink's target. The other is providing the cell where you want to put the hyperlink. As far as I know, you cannot create a UDF that will return a hyperlink in a cell. So, this is what I would do.

```
Sub MakeHyperLink(linkLocation as Range, linkTarget as Range, displayText as String)

    Dim targetAddress as String
    Dim locationSheet as Worksheet

    ' Get a string form of the hyperlink address
    targetAddress = "'" & linkTarget.Parent.Name & "'!" & linkTarget.Address

    ' Get the sheet where the link will go.
    Set locationSheet linkLocation.Parent;

    ' Add the hyperlink
    locationSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=linkLocation, _
                                 Address:="", _
                                 subAddress:=targetAddress, _
                                 TextToDisplay:=displayText
End Sub
```

Comment: ...or use the `=HYPERLINK()` function as suggested in a comment on your OP by BigBen.

Comment: I have a solution for the UDF that uses HYPERLINKI() with the first part of the Macro above. I just thought one UDF would appear cleaner than using a UDF inside a native function. If going to the trouble of creating a UDF, might as well get it done all in one shot. It would be cool if HYPERLINK() was callable.